# Create a Search Collection on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-atlas

We have in our database Offices and their Customers.
We also have a Dashboard where we load groups of Customers depending on their situation. Somethings like this:

```
{
  "_id": UUID('c0f53964-bc0b-4bfc-abf1-c9aa2724c3f8'),
  "OfficeId": UUID('c0f53964-bc0b-4bfc-abf1-c9aa2724c3f8'),
  "FilterGroups": [
    {
      "_t": "GeneralFilterGroup",
      "_id": UUID('67c6b453-125b-4e83-9947-c51831d7d248'),
      "Name": "General",
      "Filters": [
        {
          "_t": "WithEmailCustomerFilter",
          "_id": UUID('4e1611f8-a76a-4768-9f81-dddf354d3034'),
          "Name": "Customers With Email",
          "CalendarYearSupported": false,
          "Specifications": [
            {
              "_id": UUID('85916632-b3c3-4a5b-a4f7-c1b9f9099670'),
              "CalendarYear": {
                "_id": 0
              },
              "CustomerIds": [
                UUID('da665d48-ded3-4665-8c82-15448f4d3031'),
                UUID('93546365-7bb6-421e-aa58-d1c1269ce4ab'),
                UUID('01d47986-2860-478f-abd7-45bac600de51'),
                UUID('9bb32769-47b3-4ef9-9572-db015a3eae01'),
                UUID('246fd357-ea48-4710-b833-20b59e47b188'),
                UUID('a0acb9b2-224a-41a4-ba2c-5947db304ba5')
              ],
              "Analyzer": {
                "_t": "WithEmailSpec"
              },
              "Count": 6
            }
          ],
          "TotalCustomers": {
            "$numberLong": "74"
          }
        },
        {
          "_t": "WithoutEmailCustomerFilter",
          "_id": UUID('afaca2ae-5e30-4568-8dd7-73a895c839f4'),
          "Name": "Customers Without Email",
          "CalendarYearSupported": false,
          "Specifications": [
            {
              "_id": UUID('f3a2cc25-7a9b-4ee8-b10a-e6e8acd4c042'),
              "CalendarYear": {
                "_id": 0
              },
              "CustomerIds": [
                UUID('d920c2af-db60-489b-96d0-9049c68c8ce2'),
                UUID('392b1bed-662d-4436-a7fb-d56ced10cb64'),
                UUID('3daab319-5c02-4954-97e9-af53b076be75'),
                UUID('ba1a6871-3801-4a28-8e96-56b8d308df48'),
                UUID('9bbeda51-fa57-455d-84a0-957c7f876229'),
                UUID('9aff5c8a-dee3-4e00-9a6c-954a16bf4240'),
                UUID('22975a5c-898f-4b6f-b7a2-a08598473c02')                
              ],
              "Analyzer": {
                "_t": "WithoutEmailSpec"
              },
              "Count": 7
            }
          ],
          "TotalCustomers": {
            "$numberLong": "7"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Version": 1
}
```

```
Customers = [
    {
        _id: UUID('d920c2af-db60-489b-96d0-9049c68c8ce2'),
        Name: "Ivan Casanova",
        Status: 0,
        Email: null,
        Statements : [
            {
                CalendarYear: {
                    _id: 2021
                },
                Balance: 5000
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

Active, Inactive, WithEmail, WithoutEmail. Other information from other collections like Statements for each year and so on.
Right now, we update this Dash, using events in our Cloud provider. The problem is, everyday we lose some data in the Dash. So every night we have to go querying all our data to reconstruct our Dashboard. And yet, some Offices complain missing data and we have to reconstruct that, via manual tools.

I am studying a solution for that. Until now my idea was to use the MongoDBAtlas Triggers and Functions to update the Dash based on Database events. I think if the MongoDBAtlas itself managing the data would work better.

However, I know I could also make an aggregation and a **VIEW** with all this data.

So, I am here wondering what aproach would be less expensive, both in money and performance.

We have something like 800.000 Customers and 3000 Offices in our Database.
So I ask what aproach would be more effective and advisable in my case scenario.

Also the way we do things now, we can't concatenate some of the different attributes of Office's Customers. Would be nice to improve that.

But most important is what would worth our efforts:

1. Triggers and Functions (several of them doing the updates to the
   Dash Collections).
2. A huge View built from an Aggregation, grouping
   by OFficeId, Situation, Status, WithEmail etc.
3. I am open to sugestions.